# WCF host in Windows Service: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: windows, wcf, service

Many WCF services hosted in one windows.
  When windows service is just running, the wcf service endpoints are working well. After a long-time running, the wcf service is down. Though, this time the load is not heavy but instead, the services down.

After down, when I visit the endpoint through Internet browser or client app, they both throw the following exception.

```
    System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 
    There was no endpoint listening at http://serviceip/servicename that could accept 
the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, 
    if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned 
    an error: (404) Not Found.
```

I have no idea about this problem. Do anyone know anything about this, pls help.
  thanks in advance.

Comment: SOS 
Has anyone know somethong about this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the code? Especially the services code itself and the app.config for its endpoints?

Comment: If you have hosted the WCF service using windows service and if the windows service is down, so will the WCF service be. Let me know if we are not on the same page.

Comment: Any related messages in event log?

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that your parameters are out of sync or the hosting service may have been modified. Check and make sure your parameters case (if the host is case sensitive) and then ensure you are passing the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to turn on tracing on WCF services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx?