# WCF host in windows service: cannot get wsdl

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wsdl, dns, basichttpbinding

i've a windows service that hosts a WCF service with basicHTTPBinding. In test everything goes right, when i deploy the win service on a Window Server 2003, service hosts correctly wcf, I print out endpoints in tracing, they're correct, but when i ask for wsdl using the address that service exposed (i.e. http://mybaseaddress/?wsdl) i get a dns error, i cannot get the page!

Where i fail? I miss something? If i host the wcf with a console app, using the same config file, i can get the wsdl without problems!

Thank you in advance
Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys,it's monday! I've found the solution, was under my eyes!!

Here the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476913/wcf-host-in-windows-service-system-net-webexception-the-remote-server-returned) that save me!

This question can be closed!